# Regexp for all numbers or just one specific symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to verify if string consists of numbers only or just with one '*' symbol.

Correct:

```
*
123
5
```

Incorrect:

```
**
23*
*2
abc
```

I've tried `new RegExp('[\*?|\d*]')` but it doesn't allow numbers and allow multiple `*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about that : `^(?:\*|\d+)$`

?: is for non capturing group.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case.

var r = new RegExp('[^(?:\*|\d+)$]');
r.test('*1')
true
r.test('*')
false
r.test('1')
true

Comment: what did you expect? empty string should be true or false?

Comment: That's because you're creating the regex from a string and not escaping the '\'. Try `var r = new RegExp('[^(?:*|\\d+)$]');` or `var r = /[^(?:*|\d+)$]/;`

Comment: and the wildcard `*` should be escaped too. and my `regexp` does not have `[]` arround.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: "^\d*$"

^: start of the string, $: end of the string

Answer (score 0):

There You go :

```
(^\*{1}$|^\d+$)
```

tested in notepad++

Comment: `{1}` is always not required.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `RegExp.test` and `String.match` functions:

```
var checkString = function(str){
    var ast_matches = str.match(/[*]/g);  // asterisk symbol matches
        return /^[*\d]+$/.test(str) && (!ast_matches || ast_matches.length === 1);
    };

console.log(checkString("1235"));      // true
console.log(checkString("*1235"));     // true
console.log(checkString("**23*2abc")); // false
```

Comment: \*1235 must be false, str.match(/[*]/g).length produce error if there no any *

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex: `^(\*|[0-9]*)$`:

- `^...$` for matching the whole line
- `(|)` for defining two alternatives
- `\*` alternative 1: one star only
- `[0-9]*` alternative 2: numbers only

You can play with the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/rC2hV4/3).

You can create the regex object like this: `new RegExp(/^[0-9]*\*?[0-9]*$/);` I.e. without the apostrophes. You can play with that [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zy0jtxzq/3/).

Comment: \*123 must be false, * allowed only in case if * is alone